# javascript return property value from nested array of objects based on condition

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, ecmascript-6

i have an array of objects, in which each object could have an array of objects inside.

```
var mylist = [
    {
        "email" : null, 
        "school" : "schoolA",
        "courses": [
            {
                "name" : 'ABC', 
                "type" : "chemistry"
            }, 
            {
                "name" : 'XYZ',
                "type": "math"
            }
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "email" : null,
        "school": "schoolB"
    }
];
```

i want to return course name if one of the course type is chemistry.
The course types are unique and even if they are some duplicates, we return the first one.

```
var result = mylist.some(function (el) {
            el.courses && el.courses.some(function(u) {
              if (u.type === 'chemistry') {
                 return u.name;
              };    
            })
        });

console.log('outcome:', result);
```

my code is not working at this stage.

Comment: You must use the `find` function to find the right course object and then return the name of the found course. The function `some` only returns a boolean value with the value of the given predicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `some` callback should return a truthy or falsy value, which tells `some` whether to keep going (`true` = stop), and `some` returns a boolean, not a callback return value.

Probably simplest in this case just to assign directly to `result`:

```
var result;
mylist.some(function(el) {
    return (el.courses || []).some(function(course) {
        if (course.type === "chemistry") {
            result = course.name;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Live Example:

```js
var mylist = [
    {
        "email" : null, 
        "school" : "schoolA",
        "courses": [
            {
                "name" : 'ABC', 
                "type" : "chemistry"
            }, 
            {
                "name" : 'XYZ',
                "type": "math"
            }
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "email" : null,
        "school": "schoolB"
    }
];

var result;
mylist.some(function(el) {
    return (el.courses || []).some(function(course) {
        if (course.type === "chemistry") {
            result = course.name;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    });
});
console.log(result);
```

---

I stuck to ES5 syntax since you didn't use any ES2015+ in your question, but in ES2015+, simplest probably to use nested `for-of` loops:

```
let result;
outer: for (const el of mylist) {
    for (const course of el.courses || []) {
        if (course.type === "chemistry") {
            result = course.name;
            break outer;
        }
    }
}
```

Live Example:

```js
const mylist = [
    {
        "email" : null, 
        "school" : "schoolA",
        "courses": [
            {
                "name" : 'ABC', 
                "type" : "chemistry"
            }, 
            {
                "name" : 'XYZ',
                "type": "math"
            }
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "email" : null,
        "school": "schoolB"
    }
];

let result;
outer: for (const el of mylist) {
    for (const course of el.courses || []) {
        if (course.type === "chemistry") {
            result = course.name;
            break outer;
        }
    }
}
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `reduce()` method to iterate through each object in array and then `find()` method to find if some course matches type.

```js
var mylist = [{"email":null,"school":"schoolA","courses":[{"name":"ABC","type":"chemistry"},{"name":"XYZ","type":"math"}]},{"email":null,"school":"schoolB"}]

const course = mylist.reduce((r, {courses}) => {
  if (courses && !r) {
    const course = courses.find(({type}) => type == 'chemistry');
    if (course) r = course.name;
  }
  return r;
}, null)

console.log(course)
```

Comment: Yes, reduce keeps going but at least find doesn't starts.

Comment: Yeah, it's a *really* quick callback for the remaining elements. :-)